# How to solve pkg_resources.VersionConflict error during bin/python bootstrap.py -d

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am tring to create a new plone environment using python plone-devstart.py tool. I got a bootstrap error. So i used a command bin/python bootstrap.py -d from my project directory. It(bin/python bootstrap.py -d command) worked fine before But now i got an error like

```
oomsys@oomsysmob-6:~/demobrun$ bin/python bootstrap.py -d
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-  
0.6.49.tar.gz
Extracting in /tmp/tmpDqVwYA
Now working in /tmp/tmpDqVwYA/distribute-0.6.49
Building a Distribute egg in /tmp/tmpv4Bzyv
/tmp/tmpv4Bzyv/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bootstrap.py", line 118, in <module>
ws.require('zc.buildout' + VERSION)
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 698, in require
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 600, in resolve
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (setuptools 0.6c11 (/home/oomsys/demobrun  
/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg),    
Requirement.parse('setuptools>=0.7'))
```

Comment: Your problem is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586987/how-to-solve-pkg-resources-versionconflict-error-during-bin-python-bootstrap-py

Comment: But as a note, I've not found a solution to this either

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be working in a virtualenv located in `/home/oomsys/demobrun`. The error message is stating that `setuptools` is of version 0.6c11, where 0.7 or higher is required. You can use `pip` to upgrade the package to the current release:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: What about my use case where I'm not working in a virtualenv? I'm having the same issue. the only way for me to work around this error was to force zc.buildout to use an older version.

Comment: @Andre No. Just do `sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools` to install the `site-packages` Python package (note the `sudo`!). The Ubuntu installed setuptools package is in `dist-packages` still and you can manage `site-packages` using `pip` and `dist-packages` using `apt-get`.